# Identify this time-traveling RPG

Tags: product-identification, time-travel

I have heard tell--though never played--an RPG based on the following premise:

- PCs work for a company and are sent on missions in time;
- The vagaries of time travel being what they are, sending "important" people through time is risky (paradoxes!)
- So PCs are thoroughly unimpressive schmoes.

Anyone know the game? Is it still readily available?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is it [*Time & Temp*](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/64199/time-temp) (2009)? Most time-travel RPGs are more-or-less serious takes on the idea, with the PCs being heroes or daring Time Agents and similar, but *Time & Temp* PCs are definitely under-appreciated and sub-heroic:

> Employed by Marigold Staffing and working at Browne Chronometric Engineering, Inc., you travel through the ages actualizing solutions for the anomalies and paradoxes that threaten all of existence. You are reality’s only line of defense in the war between the rigidity of causality and freewill. And your only reward is the hard earned satisfaction of a job well done (plus $11.50 an hour and a modest health package including comprehensive immunizations for history’s most prolific diseases).

*Time & Temp: Paperless Office Edition* (read: “PDF edition”) is inexpensively available [at DriveThruRPG](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/79342/Time--Temp-Paperless-Office-Edition) and [Indie Press Revolution](http://www.indiepressrevolution.com/xcart/product.php?productid=17118&page=5).

It was also initially released in print (*Time & Temp: Unbound Edition*, a loose-leaf edition that looks like employee files), but I can't find evidence that it's still in-print.

Comment: that sounds exactly like it--thanks!